# mail() not working on specific page

Tags: php, email

I have the following piece of code

```html
$to = $row['email'];
//$to      = '****';
$subject = 'Test';
$message = "Test";

$headers = array(
    'From' => '****',
    'Reply-To' => '****',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  echo "Mail sent to: " . $to;
} else {
  echo "Mail failed to: " . $to;
}
```

This code isn't working in one specific page, it shows the mail sent message but its not received, I've checked the spam box as well but not there. The email address is correct, I've tried hard coding it and its still not received.

Whats strange is this code works fine on other page (through with different subject/message)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I think it is, because he wouldnt be able to send mails from other pages also if its not setup.

Comment: can you try `var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));` and let us know what does it print?

Comment: @new_user good point

Comment: The only other difference hat I can think of is this code is within a functional whereas the working one isnt

Comment: It doesn't fundamentally matter whether you call something from a `function` or not. We cannot diagnose the issue given the limited information we have.